# detecting a referer inside getHTTPRequestData and creating mutiple structs

Tags: struct, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

ok, so my first quesion is, i can get headers value of referrer from it, but is it always avaliable even when we have notifications enabled,

and secondly i am trying to use a member function to add two `structs` with `keypair` values to existing structure how can i fix that

here is my try but it is erroring out

```
myStruct={a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5};
myInsert=myStruct.insert({"k":10},{"x":"20"}));
WriteDump(myStruct);
```

Comment: For the 2nd question, `StructInsert()` might be the function you want.  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structinsert.html

Comment: yes you are right, but how to add multiple key/pair using a member function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the right answer

```
<cfscript>
    
    myStruct={a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5};
    myStruct.append({"k":10, "x":"20"});
    WriteDump(myStruct);
    
</cfscript>
```

See: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=3f45d026-bfdc-467f-a454-ce152bf3d44d/aedb16e6-ab4b-4693-870e-98230d81f3d1/2671c722-3e48-45c8-b0bb-61debc7261e3.cfm